# Square POS Web API Android browser error

Tags: square-connect

having an issue with Square POS Web API on Android.

We are trying to implement a kiosk app and the kiosk browser is Android based.

If run in Chrome browser the Square app loads fine with no error however if loaded in an Android browser (eg Dolphin) it fails with the following error.

Point of Sale API must be started with startActivityForResult() in the same task. It looks like the caller either used startActivity() or used startActivityForResult() from a finished activity or with the FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK flag.

How can we fix this so the app can be used in kiosk apps that use android browser?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Square POS Web API only works with Chrome intents. Therefore you must use the Chrome browser with your Android device. We are in the process of updating our documentation to reflect this information, sorry for any confusion!

Comment: Could this please be changed? I'd like to use my POS app within the app "Fully Kiosk Browser" on Android but this silly use of only Chrome-originated intents prevents that. Please let any browser/browser container app be able to launch the app with the payment intent.